# Async initiator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

It's been frequently used that we initiate a variable synchronously.

```
const x = call_a_sync_function();
```

But when the initiator becomes async, there would be a problem.

```
const x = await call_an_async_function(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

I tried anonymous async initiator, it's not perfect.

```
let x;
(async () => x = await call_an_async_function())();
export function func() {
  call(x); // x would be undefined if func() is called too early.
}
```

Then I tried to export the function in the anonymous async initiator, failed again.

```
(async () => {
  const x = await call_an_async_function();
  export function func() { // SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    call(x);
  }
)();
```

So, is there a better solution?

Comment: Not really. You have to go asynchronous all the way up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). Asynchronous code can't be turned into synchronous. If a promise is used in an export then a promise should be exported:

```
const x = call_an_async_function();
export async function func() {
  call(await x);
}
```

Once there are promises, promise-based control flow is propagated everywhere the order of execution and error handling should be maintained, up to entry point:

```
import { func } from '...';

(async () => {
  await func();
  ...
})().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Excellent, that is the perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap everything into an async function,

```
async function getX() => {let x = await call_an_async_function()); return x;}
function func() {
  call(x); // x would be undefined if func() is called too early.
}

async function main(){
   let x = await getX()
   func();
}

main()
```

Once `top-level-await` becomes part of ecmascript ( [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)), you wont have to wrap your await in async function and can use `await` at top level.

Comment: It's better than the anonymous async initiator. But it still needs to call "getX()" manually. When the number of files of async initiators increases, there would be numerous "getX()" functions which need to be exported and called in "main". Is it possible to eliminate the manual call?

Answer (score 0):

Now, we can use `--harmony-top-level-await` with node.